# Forward ApplicationEvent to RabbitMQ using funtions

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-function

My application should spread some event from a component to some rabbit message publisher.

My component fires the event using `ApplicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(e)`

On the other side, a message producer should receive the event, process it then publish it to a rabbit queue.

I'm using **spring cloud stream** and **spring cloud function** for messaging part:

```
@Configurationn
MessagingConfig {
@Autowired
StreamBridge sb; 

@EventListener
void handleEvent(Event e){
sb.send("topic", e)
}
```

Is there to rely on function rather `StreamBridge`

```
@Bean
Supplier<Event> messageProducer(){
//Get the event and publish it
}
```

Or considering ApplicationEventListener as binder

```
Function<Event, Event> messageProcessor(){
// redirect event to rabbit binder
}
```

I'm a confused.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The `@EventListener` and `StreamBridge` combination is an easier way to achieve your task. For a `Supplier` variant you need some intermediate buffer (`Flux`?) where you would place your events. And that would be a bit involved with a `Flux.create()` API: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#producing.create.

It is possible to use Spring Integration `ApplicationEventListeningMessageProducer` to catch those events and produce them to the binding's `MessageChannel`.